# Is there a way to lookup the column header from the row hear and row value?

Tags: excel-formula

Looking for some help...
Is there a way to get the column header name based off the row header name and a value within the body, please note that there are duplicates.

For example from the below table based on RowH2 and table body X, the col1 and col3 column header names should be provided.

```
           Col1  Col2 Col3
RowH1      X    
RowH2      X          X
RowH3            X
```

Thanks

Comment: provided how?  In the same cell delimited somehow?  In different cells?

Comment: In another table that has the same row names.
i.e. the answers will be presented in a table like below;

RowH1   Col1
RowH2   Col1   Col3
RowH3   Col2

Comment: I have used a formula =IF((COLUMNS($G13:G13)<=$F13),INDEX(DateHeadings,,SMALL(IF(TableBodyRow="E",COLUMN(DateHeadings)-4+1),COLUMNS($G13:G13))),"") however because "TableBodyRow" is a named range is makes an absolute, and I want to be able to avoid absolute reference that is created and having to change it via name manager